# Flashing black screen after explosions in Modern Warfare 2 - Graphics card malfunction in Bootcamp

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2, macos, boot-camp

I'm running Modern Warfare 2 on bootcamp, 2gb ram and an nVidia 9400m.  Every now and then, an explosion messes up my display and it starts flashing black. and I can see through walls (honest to god, I'm not hacking).  Exiting the current round usually solves the problem temporarily, but I'd like it not to happen at all.

Does anyone else have this problem? Why does it happen? And what can I do to solve it?

PS it used to cause a bsod, but then I updated the drivers.

PPS For those of you who are curious, apart from this one problem, Modern Warfare 2 is otherwise very playable on bootcamp and it only happens every once in a while.

Edit: Just adding to the answer: The solution seems to be a program called [lubbofancontrol](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lubbofancontrol/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This forum discussion](http://www.overclock.net/nvidia/744133-modern-warfare-2-screen-flash-then.html) raises the possibility that your problem is a result of either a bad driver or overclocking the GPU/shaders on your graphics card. A suggested solution for the latter is to turn the GPU fan up...just a possibility, though.

Comment: Do you know how to do this on a macbook in bootcamp?  Now I'm worried that I might have damaged my graphics card while playing... :(

Comment: [this](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=324455) suggest that you are absolutely correct.